# How to Set variable value as a DataTable name in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, object, datatable

I would like to set variable value as DataTable name in c# dynamically because variable name will change every time i run .
How do i say ,

```
String mydatatablename="MyDT1";
 DataTable mydatatablename= new DataTable();
```

then i will assign this mydatatablename  to a Gridview in my project.As shown below,

```
 mydatatablename   = ds1.Tables[0];

            GridProduct.DataSource = mydatatablename  ;
            GridProduct.DataBind();
```

Comment: Then what is the issue that you are facing?

Comment: That he's doing 2 different things with the same variable. First he assigns a string "MyDT1" to `mydatatablename`, and then he tries to create a `new DataTable()` in the same variable.

Comment: Assuming `ds1` is DataSet, you can get any table from DataSet having `tablename = "MyDT1"` by callling `GridProduct.DataSource = ds1.Tables[mydatatablename]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that in this way. You can create a `Dictionary<string, DataTable>` to store that data though.

Example:

```
Dictionary<string, DataTable> mydts = new Dictionary<string, DataTable>();

String dt1 = "mydatatable1";

mydts.Add(dt1, new DataTable());
```

And then:

```
control.DataSource = mydts[dt1];
```

You cant have a dynamic names of variables in C#, but you can have a collection of objects where key is name, which can be variable string.

More info about `Dictionary` can be found  [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx)

I hope that helps.